# AngularJS keeps me telling my Controller is not a function

Tags: angularjs

When I run my Application in Browser, the console tells me :

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'FlightListController' is not a function, got undefined

'FlightListController' is bound to my index.html via "ng-view"

```
<div class="container" ng-view="FlightListController"></div>
```

and is imported accordingly at the end of my index.html

```
<script src="app/controller/FlightListController.js"></script>
```

The FlightListController.js content is:

```
var app = angular.module("flightlog");

app.controller("Flight", function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get("http://localhost:3000/flights").success(function (response) {
    $scope.flights = response;
}).error(function (err) {
    $scope.error = err;
});
```

Now i don't have any clue what the Angular Error wants to tell me. The [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=FlightListController&p1=not) hidden behind the error doesn't really help.

Comment: isn't your controller called "Flight", not "FlightListController"? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("flightlog");

app.controller("FlightListController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/flights").success(function (response) {
    $scope.flights = response;
  }).error(function (err) {
    $scope.error = err;
  });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="FlightListController">
```

Comment: It's always my blindness for typos after some hours of coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are telling the view wich is his controller you should use:

ng-controller not ng-view

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="FlightListController">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController - Documentation